# python3 subclass error 'object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with python 3.11 and am having issues with subclassing the File object.  I basically want to be able to perform a write operation and attach a newline character to each string without having to explicitly add the newline to each string being written.

So, I want to replace:

```
    with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('some text' + '\n')
```

with:

```
    with MyOpen('filename.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.wl('some text')
```

I am reusing code found here and submitted by Ethan Furman. Here is his class definition:

```
    class Open(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
            # do custom stuff here
            self.args = args
            self.kwds = kwds
        def __enter__(self):
            # or do custom stuff here :)
            self.file_obj = open(*self.args, **self.kwds)
            # return actual file object so we don't have to worry
            # about proxying
            return self.file_obj
        def __exit__(self, *args):
            # and still more custom stuff here
            self.file_obj.close()
            # or here
```

I am now trying to subclass from his class (which subclasses from "object" which is being used as a file object).

```
    class MyOpen(Open):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
        def wl(self, string):
            super().file_obj.writelines(string + '\n')
```

I use the class as was mentioned at the top.  When I run my script, I get the following error:

```
    outfile.wl(f"Input file is {path}")
        ^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'wl'
```

I'm a bit of a newby with python, so my understanding is rather fragmented.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `outfile` is a reference to `self.file_obj`, which is the returned value from `open()`. So of course its returned value does not have the `wl` property of the `MyOpen` object, because it is an `_io.TextIOWrapper`. You are explicitly returning a `_io.TextIOWrapper` but expecting it to have the properties of a custom object. I'm not sure why you would expect that. You maybe could just do `return self` from the `enter` function, and cause the code to behave how you want, but that would be weird. You're not really dealing with closing the file in that case, which is the whole point of `with`.

Comment: You don't need `super` to access an instance attribute. `self.file_obj.writelines(string + "\n")` is sufficient.

Comment: Also `writelines` is the wrong method to use if you want to write a single line.

Comment: @RandomDavis It's not that weird. It's basically how context managers for `IOBase` work: `__enter__` just checks that the underlying file is, in fact, open, and `__exit__` just closes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` statements to not automatically provide a reference to the context manager; they provide a reference to whatever the context manager's `__enter__` method returns.

```
with Foo() as f:
    ...
```

is not equivalent (ignoring a lot of details) to

```
f = Foo()
f.__enter__()
...
f.__exit__()
```

but rather

```
t = Foo()
f = t.__enter__()
...
t.__exit()
```

(See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for a fuller description of how `with` actually behaves.)

---

Since `Open.__enter__` returns a file-like object, not the `Open` instance itself, you can't use methods define only on `Open`. You can return the `Open` instance itself (and provide your own wrapper around the file's `write` method)

```
class Open:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # do custom stuff here
        self.args = args
        self.kwds = kwds

    def __enter__(self):
        # or do custom stuff here :)
        self.file_obj = open(*self.args, **self.kwds)
        # return actual file object so we don't have to worry
        # about proxying
        return self

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.file_obj.write(*args, **kwargs)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # and still more custom stuff here
        self.file_obj.close()
        # or here
```